# Processing sketches in eclipse not working as expected

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, processing

In eclipse(or VS code) the sketch window is larger than what is defined in the sketch, in the size() function. For example, even though in the code it is size(800,600); the window of the sketch is 1000 X 750, for some reason. Is there a way to fix this. Also the shapes have jagged edges(perhaps because of this resizing).Is their a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because Processing is only rendering a quarter of the pixels created for the canvas. This is probably because the pixel density is set to 1. Simply run: `pixelDensity(2);` and this should fix the problem. If you don't know what the pixel density of your monitor is, run: `pixelDensity(displayDensity());`

Here's some documentation:
https://processing.org/reference/pixelDensity_.html

Comment: The same code produces smaller window in processing ide and a larger on in eclipse.